# Tilemill grey border on mbtiles export

Tags: tilemill, mbtiles

I've got my final raster tile map (via vrt) into tilemill and am trying different mbtiles export options. No matter what boundary I specify for export - I always end up with the beige top and bottom bands.

How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was nothing to do with tilemill.

Basically, the beige bands are areas that are visible when brought into Xcode (.mbtiles). Using the map box sdk framework, set the backgroundView.backgroundcolor property of the mapView to a blue ocean colour, or whatever is appropriate. it was showing beige as it had no backgroundView.